# How can I ask a question about somebody else's question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, specific-question

How can I post a question on someone else's question? Are you only allowed to post answers on questions? Can I use the same one?

For example, see this Stack Overflow question: [How do I make Javascript beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep)

There is an accepted answer for that question. I have tried it, but in my situation it is not working. So how can I ask about that?

Answer (score 4):

If the question isn't yours, you post a new question linking to the existing question and stating what you have tried.

If the original question you need to extend is yours, then you edit it.

Comment: When i tried that, page is refreshing but nothing is coming out.It is not giving option to enter any thing. Please help me,

Comment: Do we need any badge to link up? I dont have any thing.

Comment: @user: You posted a question here on Meta, right? Just do what you did here, except on SO itself.

Comment: What is the meaning of SO?

Comment: Here i have click on 'Ask Question' to post a new question.Now i want to post question on already asked question? Do you want to post a new question eventhough it is already asked?

Comment: @user SO means Stack Overflow. What Sid said goes for any site, though. You cannot post a question "on" another question. Usually posting duplicate questions is discouraged, but in this case you may not have a choice.

Comment: ok thanku. I posted another question

Comment: Convenience link to [the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981377/generate-sound-using-javascript)

Comment: i think i have similar problem, I see that "Add comment" link here but not in SO. I want to comment on someone's answer.  From FAQ, there's a note "† you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep." Does this mean I cannot post comment to questions I didn't ask without any rep?

Comment: @user152548 That's correct.  If you want to comment on someone else's answer (for a question you didn't ask) you need a minimum amount of reputation to do so.